# Is there a way to manage tokens from backend with next auth?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

You want to manage user authentication with next.js.

I think it would be good to use next auth, but is there a way to give next auth the refresh token and access token I got from the backend server so I can only manage it?

So I want to manage the access token and refresh token that I get from the server with next auth.

Is there a good way to do this?